# React Components not Clickable on Page and doesn't Show up on Inspect

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am improving some features for an existing web site built with ReactJS but on home page I can only click on Body tag, so if I put an onClick event on one of the components, it doesn't fire up.
Here is an image of what I am trying to say
[image]

I am trying to click on buttons in Cards but inspect points Body tag. So, If you face this issue before or know how to fix this please share it here.
Thank you.

Edit:
I am seeing a second HTML tag inside a usual HTML tag, which inspector currently pointing to when hovering any element on page. So probably this is the problem. Know the reason? Please share.
[image]

Comment: try to look for some `z-index` property.

Comment: can you put some code here

Comment: Couldn't find any z-index issue here. Actually, the website works on the server as expected but in my local it doesn't work. I just can't click the elements on the page.

Comment: Reviewed again and yes you are right it is a z-index problem. Problem solved, thanks for the help.